# What is the simplest way to save basic processing instructions with my XmlDocument in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

In my code:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement book = document.CreateElement("book");
document.AppendChild(book);

... // create and add a bunch of nodes

document.Save(filename);
```

I want to modify my code so that the string `<?xml version="1.0"?>` is saved at the top of `filename`. What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without manipulating the document, you can provide the `Save` method with an `XmlWriter`, which writes the XML declaration by default:

```
    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(filename))
    {
        document.Save(xw);
    }
```

Comment: This works, but for some reason now my document prints all on one line (instead of pretty printing). It's not that big a deal, but it would help with debugging for it to pretty print. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with [XmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType, string, string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extfcy1c.aspx) overload by specifying `XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration`. This should add a declaration node to the document.

Answer (score 1):

This should work and also pretty-print the output:

```
using(var writer =
  XmlWriter.Create(filename, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
{
  document.Save(writer);
}
```